# Canvas HTML 5 image transition effect

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have made an image slide show by using HTML 5 canvas.
But now I want to add an image sliding effect to it. I have tried it but can't get it to work properly.

Transition should be such that the 1st image which is already rendered should be below the 2nd image that slides on to the 1st image. 1st image should not be cleared.

```
var pathToYourImages =  [
    "images/image1.png",
    "images/image2.png", 
    "images/image3.jpg", 
    "images/image4.jpg", 
  ];

var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;
var image = null;
var currentImage = 0;
var scrollVal = 0;
var x=0;
var y=0;
var scale=0;
var speed =2;

window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    image = document.createElement("img");
    currentImage = 0;
    setTimeout(loop, 100);       
};

function loop(){
    setTimeout(update, 10);
    setTimeout(scaleToFit, 10);
    setTimeout(render, 10);
    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}

function update(){
    image.setAttribute('src', pathToYourImages[currentImage]);
    currentImage = currentImage == (pathToYourImages.length-1) ? 0 : ++currentImage;
}

function scaleToFit(){
    scale = Math.min(canvas.width / image.width, canvas.height / image.height);
    x = (canvas.width / 2) - (image.width / 2) * scale;
    y = (canvas.height / 2) - (image.height / 2) * scale;
}

function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(image, x, y, image.width * scale, image.height * scale);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, your code is a mess. Try using only one loop, preferably `window.requestAnimationFrame(callbackFunction)` Instead of a `scaleToFit` loop I'd advise you make use of the `resize` event of the `window`

Comment: There is no guarantee that your image has been fully loaded when you call the `drawImage` you need to incorporate `image.load` in your code